# How can I create gallery of products and submit data for each product?

Tags: taxonomy, e-commerce

I have a client that wants an eCommerce contact to order website. The client wants to submit products on the website, including the price, name, and information for the product. Along with that, the "contact to order" would be clicking the button for each product, it'll go to a form and contact the site owner for purchase (I can do that part).

But this will be my first time really developing with WordPress other then creating a theme for it. I have no clue how I should get started with this project.

There is a feature on WordPress called Taxonomies, as I read it might be what I need. Is this correct? If not, what would be the best solution for creating products and showing them on the website? Is there a plugin for this?

Answer (score 0):

have a look on here for e-commerce and then go install WooCommerce or GetShopped

Thi should be easiest and you wont need to do much development .... as you want to 'contact to order'

This might also help: http://wordpress.damien.co/2012/07/choose-the-right-wordpress-e-commerce-solution-for-you/